# Countdown won't stop at 0, keeps decrementing

Tags: javascript

I have a timer that keeps decrementing after 0 so I get negative numbers. Time starts when a button is clicked and the pauses when the same button is clicked again.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    console.log('timer started')
    // Timer paused, click to start

            // Pause/Play Timer
            if(timeleft == 90){
                timeleft = setInterval(function() {
                    time--;
                    timerDisplay.innerHTML = time;
                }, 1000);
            } else if (timeleft === 0) {
                clearInterval(timeleft);
            } else{   
            // Timer running, click to pause
              console.log('timer paused')
                clearInterval(timeleft);
                timeleft = 90;
            }
        });
```

The stop and start functionality works fine but why won't it stop counting down once it reaches 0?

Comment: None of your variables are declared; they're all global. This is definitely a problem

Comment: You need to clear the interval from inside the callback.

Comment: You're using `timeleft` as the return result of `setInterval()` as well as an integer. That won't work.

Comment: an edge case issue .... `timeleft = setInterval(...` could end up with `timeleft` equalling 90 - because `setInterval` can return 90 - also ` if (timeleft === 0)` doesn't check if `time` is 0

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for reference to build a timer.

```js
const actionBtn = document.getElementById("start-timer");
let isTimerRunning =  false;
let interval = null;
let maxTime = 20;

// Click handler to start and stop timer button in DOM
actionBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(isTimerRunning) {
    // stop timer 
    stopTimer();
  } else {
    // start timer
    startTimer();
  }
});

// Function to start timer
function startTimer() {
  isTimerRunning = true; // toggle state, so on click again we can stop timer
  // 1sec interval function to reduce max time
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    maxTime = maxTime - 1;
    if(maxTime > -1) { // if the more time left (more than 0) update UI
      renderUi(`Reset (${maxTime}sec)`);
    } else { // if there is no time left stop timer
      stopTimer();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

// stop timer
function stopTimer() {
  isTimerRunning = false; // toggle state, so on click again we can start timer
  clearInterval(interval); // clear the interval
  maxTime = 20; // reset max time to initial value
  renderUi(`Start Timer (${maxTime}sec)`); // update UI to initial value
}

// A generic function to update UI
// if we have complet UI structure we can update this function
function renderUi(str) {
  actionBtn.innerText = str;
}
```

```html
<button id="start-timer">Start Timer (20sec)</button>
```